# SQL Subquery - Repeat Where Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is a 101 question, but do I need to repeat the Where clause in the main query in the sub-query below? It appears to give me the same either way, but is it even needed?

```
  FROM account a
LEFT JOIN account pa ON a.parentaccountid = pa.accountid
JOIN customeraddress ca ON a.accountid = ca.parentid
JOIN optionsetmetadata osm ON osm.entityname = 'customeraddress'
    AND osm.optionsetname = 'addresstypecode'
    AND ca.addresstypecode = osm.[option]
LEFT JOIN sik_warehouse w ON a.sik_warehouseid = w.sik_warehouseid
LEFT JOIN sik_deliverymethods dm ON a.sik_deliverymethodid = dm.sik_deliverymethodsid

WHERE a.accountnumber IN ('58398',
    '4350',
    '5076',
    '4310',
    '15847')
    AND Addresstypecode = 2
    AND ca.jms_status = 100000000
    AND ca.addressnumber > (
        SELECT TOP 1 ca_sub1.addressnumber
        FROM customeraddress ca_sub1
        JOIN account a_sub1 ON ca_sub1.parentid = a_sub1.accountid
        AND ca_sub1.addressnumber > 2
        order by ca_sub1.addressnumber ASC
```

Comment: No, since you correlate the sub-query to the out-query, it's repetitive.

Comment: Probably not.  You can probably do what you want with window functions.  If only you specified what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

add inline view if you want to put multiple where condition.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Once you get enough rep you will be able to leave comments.

Comment: yeah.. i m new here. but check the que and i gave a suggetion.